# SYN packet getting no replies (Python) raw sockets

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp

Whenever I send a SYN packet using my program, I get no reply.I know the server is working because I can connect to it using the normal socket `connect()` method but when I try using RAW sockets to do it I get no reply, not even an RST.

Here is my packet according to Wireshark

```
    Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 5173 (5173), Dst Port: 5005 n (5005), Seq: 0, Len: 0
    Source Port: 5173
    Destination Port: 5005
    [Stream index: 15]
    [TCP Segment Len: 0]
    Sequence number: 0    (relative sequence number)
    Acknowledgment number: 0
    Header Length: 40 bytes
    Flags: 0x002 (SYN)
        000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
        ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
        .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
        .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
        .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
        .... ...0 .... = Acknowledgment: Not set
        .... .... 0... = Push: Not set
        .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
        .... .... ..1. = Syn: Set
        .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
        [TCP Flags: **********S*]
    Window size value: 53270
    [Calculated window size: 53270]
    Checksum: 0x9f18 [incorrect, should be 0x90ae (maybe caused by "TCP checksum offload"?)]
    Urgent pointer: 0
    Options: (20 bytes), Maximum segment size, SACK permitted, Timestamps, No-Operation (NOP), Window scale
        Maximum segment size: 65495 bytes
            Kind: Maximum Segment Size (2)
            Length: 4
            MSS Value: 65495
        TCP SACK Permitted Option: True
            Kind: SACK Permitted (4)
            Length: 2
        Timestamps: TSval 378701, TSecr 0
            Kind: Time Stamp Option (8)
            Length: 10
            Timestamp value: 378701
            Timestamp echo reply: 0
        No-Operation (NOP)
            Type: 1
                0... .... = Copy on fragmentation: No
                .00. .... = Class: Control (0)
                ...0 0001 = Number: No-Operation (NOP) (1)
        Window scale: 7 (multiply by 128)
   [SEQ/ACK analysis]
```

And here is my Python code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
from struct import *
import random

s = socket.socket()
host = "127.0.0.1"
destination = "127.0.0.1"

CLRF = '\r\n'
#socket.gethostname()
print destination
port = 5173

#s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#s.connect((host, 5005))

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

ipSource = '192.168.0.106'

#IP header

ipIHL = 5 # Header Length
ipVersion = 4 # ipv4/v6 
ipTOS = 0 # type of service
ipTotalLen = 0 ## Kernel will fill correct length apparently
ipPackID = random.randint(1,1000)

#Flags
ipReserved = 0
ipNoFrag = 1
ipMoreFrags = 0

ipFragOffset = 0 #Fragment offset
ipTTL = 64
ipProtocol = socket.IPPROTO_TCP
ipChecksum = 0 # Magic kernel filling in at work again
ipSource = socket.inet_aton (host) 
ipDest = socket.inet_aton (destination)

#Packing IP flags
ipFlags = ipMoreFrags + (ipNoFrag << 1) + (ipReserved << 2)
ipFragOffset = (ipFlags << 13) + ipFragOffset

ipIHLVersion  = (ipVersion << 4) + ipIHL

headerIP = pack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s',ipIHLVersion, ipTOS, ipTotalLen, ipPackID, ipFragOffset,  ipTTL, ipProtocol, ipChecksum, ipSource, ipDest)

#Checksum function
def carry_around_add(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return (c & 0xffff) + (c >> 16)

def checksum(msg):
    s = 0
    for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):
        w = ord(msg[i]) + (ord(msg[i+1]) << 8)
        s = carry_around_add(s, w)
    return ~s & 0xffff

#TCP Header
tcpSourcePort = port #Source Port
tcpDestPort = 5005 #Destination Port
tcpSeqNum = 0 #Packet sequence
tcpAckNum = 0 #Ackknowledge Number
tcpOffset = 10 #Size of tcp header 20 bytes
#tcpReserved = 0
#tcpECN = 0
#Control Flags
tcpURG = 0
tcpACK = 0
tcpPSH = 0
tcpRST = 0
tcpSYN = 1
tcpFIN = 0
tcpWindow = socket.htons (5840) #Dunno how this works
tcpChecksum = 0
tcpUrgentPointer = 0
#TCP Options
tcpMaxSegmentSize = (2 << 24) + (4 << 16) + 65495 # Kind + Length + Max Segment Size
tcpSACKPermitted  = (4 << 8) + 2#Kind + Length
#Split TCP TImestamps into 2 because too large

tcpTimestampPartOne = (8 << 8) + (10) #Kind + Length
tcpTimestampPartTwo = (378701 << 32) + 0 #Timestamp Value + Timestamp echo reply
tcpNoOp = (0 << 7) + (0 << 5) + 1 #Copy on fragmentation + Class + Number
tcpWindowScale = (3 << 16)+ (3 << 8) + 7 #Kind + Length(Bytes) +Shift CountS

#Combine both due to length issues
tcpNoOpAndWindowScale = (tcpNoOp << 24) + tcpWindowScale


tcpOffsetResult = (tcpOffset << 4) + 0 #Shift 4 bytes to left

#Putting together all the TCP Control Flags
tcpFlags = tcpFIN + (tcpSYN << 1) + (tcpRST << 2) + (tcpPSH << 3) + (tcpACK << 4) + (tcpURG << 5)

#Packing the pseudo TCP header
headerTCP = pack('!HHLLBBHHHLHHQL', tcpSourcePort, tcpDestPort, tcpSeqNum, tcpAckNum, tcpOffsetResult, tcpFlags, tcpWindow, tcpChecksum, tcpUrgentPointer, tcpMaxSegmentSize, tcpSACKPermitted, tcpTimestampPartOne, tcpTimestampPartTwo, tcpNoOpAndWindowScale)

#headerTCP = pack('!HHLLBBHHH', tcpSourcePort, tcpDestPort, tcpSeqNum, tcpAckNum, tcpOffsetResult, tcpFlags, tcpWindow, tcpChecksum, tcpUrgentPointer)

#data = 'GET ./asd HTTP/1.1'
data = ''

#Checksum Calculation
#Pseudo Header Fields
sourceAddr = socket.inet_aton(host)
destAddr = socket.inet_aton(destination)
placeholder = 0
protocol = socket.IPPROTO_TCP
tcpLen = len(headerTCP) + len(data)

psh = pack('!4s4sBBH', sourceAddr, destAddr, placeholder, protocol, tcpLen);
psh = psh + headerTCP + data;

#Calc checksum
tcpChecksumReal = (checksum(psh) << 1)

print(tcpChecksumReal)

#Pack actual tcp header with checksum
headerTCP = pack('!HHLLBBH', tcpSourcePort, tcpDestPort, tcpSeqNum, tcpAckNum, tcpOffsetResult, tcpFlags, tcpWindow) + pack('!H', 40728) + pack ('!H', tcpUrgentPointer) + pack('!LHHQL', tcpMaxSegmentSize, tcpSACKPermitted, tcpTimestampPartOne, tcpTimestampPartTwo, tcpNoOpAndWindowScale)

#Build full packet / ip with tcp with data
packet = headerIP + headerTCP + data
#print [hex(ord(c)) for c in packet]
s.sendto(packet, (destination,0))
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I see the wireshark said checksum is incorrect. If you do the capture on the computer that runs the python script, and your network card will not redo the checksum calculation by offloading, then the packet will NOT be accepted by any tcp stack and failed to transmit / receive.

Comment: @KenCheung Ohh right, I fixed this but is there anyway to enable offloading? I can't find anything in my searches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to @KenCheung for the answer

Turns out it was the checksum, the checksum from the headers I used as reference also were incorrect but the network card was offloading them.